# Can't retrive Date object from Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following data class:

```kotlin
data class ActivityCollectionModel(
    val id: String = "",
    val createdByUser: String = "",
    val activityTitle: String = "",
    val action: ActivityEntity.ActivityAction = ActivityEntity.ActivityAction.DefaultValue,
    val groupId: String = "",
    val date: Date = Date()
) {

    fun toDatabaseEntity(): ActivityEntity {
        return ActivityEntity(id, createdByUser, activityTitle, action, groupId)
    }
}
```

and the following method in my ViewModel -

```kotlin
private fun getGroupActivities(groupId: String, errorResults: MutableLiveData<String?>) {
        FIRESTORE_DATABASE.collection(ACTIVITIES_COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo(GROUP_ID, groupId)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                // This is the point that I convert the data to objects
                val activitiesCollectionModel = documents.toObjects(ActivityCollectionModel::class.java)
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    activitiesCollectionModel.forEach { model ->
                        Log.d("parsedModel", model.toString())
                        activitiesRepository.insertActivity(model.toDatabaseEntity())
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                exception.localizedMessage?.let { message ->
                    errorResults.value = message
                }
            }
    }
```

The issue I am facing is that when retrieving the data from Firestore the date object, which is being saved as a String, can't create a Date object back in the app so it creates a new Date, which is obviously not what I want and causes problems in my app.

Here is an image of an ActivityCollectionModel in the Cloud Firestore:

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the date is **not** being stored as a string.  It's being stored as a timestamp.  You should see "timestamp" when you hover the mouse over that field.  What is the specific problem here?  What are you observing that's different than what you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I am facing is that when retrieving the data from Firestore the date object, which is being saved as a String

As I see in your `ActivityCollectionModel` class, you are defining the `date` property:

```
val date: Date = Date()
```

As a `Date`, and not as a String, which is actually correct. However, you cannot get the value of the `date` property correctly because at every iteration you are creating a new instance rather than getting what you actually have in the database. To solve this, you should use the `@ServerTimestamp` annotation and leave the field uninitialised:

```
@ServerTimestamp
val date: Date? = null
```

Comment: That's just the default value.  It can get changed by the deserialization process, just like all the strings that also have default values.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yep, thanks, Doug.

Comment: Hi Alon! Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I have been quite busy lately and this is for a side bug but once I get back to it I'll check if your comment helped me. Thanks for now

Comment: Hey! Yes, give it a try and tell me if it works.